# Unable to Spoof DNS in Kali

Tags: phishing, kali-linux, dns-spoofing

I am new to Kali But not new to Information Security. Warming up with Kali, I tried to `dns_spoof`. But that didn't quite work. Here is what I did.

1. Tampered `ip_forward` to 1 in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4`
2. Started a credential Harvester and cloned site.
3. Set the POST payback to my own IP address.
4. In `etter.dns`, added the following.

   ```
   http://www.facebook.com
   https://www.facebook.com
   *facebook.com
   www.facebook.com
   ```
5. Ran the following command

   ```
   ettercap -T -q -i eth0 -d dns_spoof -M arp ///`<br><br>
   ```

**Problem**

When I type the IP of kali machine, I am able to get the cloned facebook.com page. But When I type, facebook.com on browser, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. How can I let it access the fake page, I have created.

**P.S** Though, I am able to catch all the SNMP packets, my router has been sending to the victim. (So, I suppose, ARP spoofing is correctly done.)

Comment: Depending on the browser you're using, you may be falling victim to preloaded HSTS lists - Facebook and other well known sites use certificate pinning which is built into the browser (see https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json - the same list is used by Firefox) and won't load if the certificate signer doesn't match the expected one. Try spoofing a smaller site - might well work.

Comment: What if, I want to tackle that as well ?

Comment: Get a certificate signed by one of the CAs referenced in that file under Facebook - "SymantecClass3EVG3", "DigiCertECCSecureServerCA", "DigiCertEVRoot", or "FacebookBackup". You'd need to get an EV certificate based on the names, in order to have the right CA chain, which you shouldn't be able to do, unless you are actually a registered company called Facebook. It's almost exactly what it's designed to protect against.

Comment: Ok, I guess, that was valid point. Another thing. How do I get css of orignal web page in my page?

Comment: @M.S.P You could also just redirect the user to faebook.com or something like that.

Comment: @Shiki  please elaborate on how can that be done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the browser you're using, you may be falling victim to preloaded HSTS lists - Facebook and other well known sites use certificate pinning which is built into the browser (see [Chrome source](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/http/transport_security_state_static.json) - the same list is used by Firefox) and won't load if the certificate signer doesn't match the expected one.

In order to defeat that, you would need to get a certificate signed by one of the CAs referenced in that file under Facebook - "SymantecClass3EVG3", "DigiCertECCSecureServerCA", "DigiCertEVRoot", or "FacebookBackup". You'd need to get an EV certificate based on the names, in order to have the right CA chain, which you shouldn't be able to do, unless you are actually a registered company called Facebook. It's almost exactly what it's designed to protect against.

You would probably be able to spoof a site which isn't on the HSTS preload lists with the settings you have.